# How do I stop my game from restarting when my pause plays my game_loop function in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pause

So, I am making a simple video game in pygame, and it is very close to finishing. I was working on my pause screen, but when I hit p(the button I chose) it paused but when I hit continue it restarted the game. I went over the code and found nothing wrong. Then, I went to the question forum here and looked up the issue, I found something but they arent doing the code like I am, and on top of that the answer is hard to understand. The pause function is `paused()` and the unpause is, suprise, `unpause()`. Can you try to find where it went wrong? Here is my scource code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600
dark_blue = (0,178,210)
blue = (109,178,201)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
brown = (102, 51, 0)
ship_width = 96
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('_Asteroid Belt_')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
thingImg = pygame.image.load("/home/pi/Desktop/asteroid.png")
shipImg = pygame.image.load('/home/pi/Desktop/spaceship.png')
bg = pygame.image.load("/home/pi/Desktop/py.png")
bgi = pygame.image.load("/home/pi/Desktop/introbg.jpg")
pause = False
def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
def unpause():
    global pause
    pause = False

def paused():


    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


        button("Start Flight",100,450,200,100,dark_blue,blue,game_loop)
        button("Land on Desktop",500,450,200,100,dark_blue,blue,quitgame)



        #pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,dark_blue,(500,450,200,100))


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.blit(bgi,(0,0))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Asteroid Belt", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


        button("Start Flight",100,450,200,100,dark_blue,blue,game_loop)
        button("Land on Desktop",500,450,200,100,dark_blue,blue,quitgame)



        #pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,dark_blue,(500,450,200,100))


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def message_display2(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)


def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count), True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))

def things(x,y, thing_width, thing_height,thing_startx,thing_starty):
    gameDisplay.blit(thingImg, (x,y))



def ship(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(shipImg,(x,y))
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, white)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()



def crash():
    message_display("You Crashed!")


def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
     mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
     click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

     if x + w>mouse[0]>x and y+h > mouse[1] >y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == game_loop:
                game_loop()
            elif action == quitgame:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
     else:
         pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,ic,(x,y,w,h))

     smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',20)
     textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,smallText)
     textRect.center = ((x+(w/2)),(y+(h/2)))
     gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)





def game_loop():
    global pause
    x = (300)
    y = (410)

    x_change=0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 5
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100
    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -20
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 20
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause = True
                    paused()



            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event .key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0



        x+= x_change

        gameDisplay.blit(bg, (0,0))  
        things(thing_startx,thing_starty,thing_width,thing_height,x,y)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        thing_height=100
        ship(x,y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - ship_width or x<0:
            crash()

        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed+=2

        if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
            cow = 5

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x+ship_width > thing_startx and x+ship_width< thing_startx +thing_width:

                crash()



        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code, I set the unpause button function to `game_loop()` instead of `unpause()`. So every time I went to unpause, I restarted the game loop! This is an example that you have to pay attention to every section of your code, not just the function thats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not unpause in your `pause()` function.

You should be adding something like this:

```
def paused():
    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.K_p:
                unpause()
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I can comment again(probably the wifi). But the if statement still sets dodged back to 0. Would there be any way to set dodged = number dodged already? Im thinking of making a function like def = continue(), but I wouldnt know the paramaters it would work off of. Could it be things_dodged? But then Im afraid it will still display 0. Let me know ASAP please.

Comment: I cannot test your code right now, but from what I can see, the value of `dodged` is never reset to 0, so not sure why you have this issue.  
Did you try to debug or log the value of `dodged` to see how it is reset to 0?

Comment: No, but I will try to see what is going on in that dodged section. I will let you know what I find